# Is there a way to view a list of Prelude functions from the Haskell console?

Tags: haskell, ghci, haskell-prelude

Is there a way to view a list of Prelude functions (such as `Data.Char`) from the Haskell console, instead of visiting Hoogle?

Comment: Note, `Data.Char` is a *module* in the *base* package. Not a Prelude function.

Answer (score 10):

From GHCi you can use

```
:browse Data.Char
```

to see the types and values exported by a given module.

E.g.

```
Prelude> :browse Data.Char
digitToInt :: Char -> Int
generalCategory :: Char -> GeneralCategory
isLetter :: Char -> Bool
isMark :: Char -> Bool
isNumber :: Char -> Bool
isPunctuation :: Char -> Bool
isSeparator :: Char -> Bool
isSymbol :: Char -> Bool
data Char = GHC.Types.C# GHC.Prim.Char#
chr :: Int -> Char
...
```

Comment: ...so you can see everything in the prelude with:  `:browse Prelude`.

Comment: Also, there's `ghc-pkg describe base` (for example) to list modules in package `base`.